# Não consigo recuperar o valor do atributo data atualizado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um data atributo igual a 1, faço atualizacao que ele vira 2 porem ao retorna-lo continua trazendo 1.

O código que faz o update seria esse :

```
$('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a').attr("data-status",status);
```

Onde que o meu `cod_sacado` vem de:

```
var cod_sacado = $(codigo).data("cod");
```

**Exemplo :**

Ele faz o update corretamente porem ao tentar retornar o valor atualizado, ele me traz o antigo e nao o atualizado.

```js
function bloquearSacado(codigo) {

    var status = "";

    var cod_sacado = $(codigo).data("cod");

    var status = $(codigo).data("status");

    if(status == "1") {
        removeAttr("data-status");
        Attr("data-status");
        var status = "2";
    } else {
        var status = "1";
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'painel/sistema/bloquearSacado',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {cod_sacado:cod_sacado, status:status},
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success == true) {
                if(status == 2) {
                    $('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a svg use').attr('href','#close_menu');
                    $('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a').css("background-color","red");
                    msgOk("Alterado com Sucesso");
                } else if(status == 1) {
                    $('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a').css("background-color","green");
                    $('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a svg use').attr('href','#ok');
                    $('[data-linha='+ cod_sacado + '] a').attr("data-status",status);
                    msgOk("Alterado com Sucesso");
                }
                else {
                    alert("lala");
                }

            } else {
                msgOk("Falha ao mudar! Atualize a página");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Teria como mostrar o que o data retorna?

Comment: Se estiver ativo meu link ele retorna 1, quando altero para 2 a primeira vez ele carrega, mas na terceira vez ao voltar ele pra 1 ele altera no html mas nao recupera no data-status